# How can I get value from URL using $this->request->params

Tags: mysql, oop, cakephp

I want to retrieve value from my url like http://localhost/totalCable/packagesignup/18

Here 18 is the value I want to retrieve.

I tried as follows:

```
$this->request->data['User']['psetting_id'] = $this->request->params['page'];
```

How I retrieve data from url?

Comment: Example of your URL would be useful to know what like (18) is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP, you can get your required URL variable like that.

```
echo $this->params['pass'][0];
```

So I think you need to write like this.

```
$this->request->data['User']['psetting_id'] = $this->params['pass'][0];
```

May be this will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
$this->request->params['page'][count($this->request->params['page'])-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how do you get URL `GET` Params?

If so, you need to use http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters

Example URL
    http://www.example.com/posts/index?page=1&sort=title

To access the page you would put

```
 $this->request->query['page'];
```

And to access the sort would be

```
 $this->request->query['page'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass id last in url to your database, you can pass it automatically to your function, see example below

http://localhost/totalCable/controller/packagesignup/18

```
public function packagesignup($id = null)
{
  print $id;
}
```

use route.php config file to map function against url properly to use according your URL structure.

http://localhost/totalCable/packagesignup/18